# R: data table non-numeric argument to binary operator

Tags: r, data.table

I am trying to assign values to selected rows in a data.table:

```
pt[4:108, dqv:=(ifelse(deg!=1,dr,0)+ifelse(deg==3, dr^2, 0)+1)*mp*shift(dcp, 4-deg)
      +(shift(cv, 4-deg)*shift(dcp, 4-deg)+shift(dqv, 4-deg)*shift(ddqp, 4-deg))*fm]
```

The error always returned is:

```
Error in (ifelse(deg != 1, dr, 0) + ifelse(deg == 3, dr^2, 0) + 1) * mp *  : 
non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

The code would work if I only assign for 1 row at a time. Such as:

```
pt[4, assignment...]
```

The assignment also fails if I do two rows, from 4:5. And done individually, the assignment works for either row 4 or 5. So it should not be a problem with NAs or characters hiding in my data.
I guess it might be that ifelse does not intake vectors as arguments. But doesn't ifelse by definition take vectors in its first argument? I have also done similar assignments to a whole column in a data.table and it worked. Perhaps I have too much datasets overhanging in memory that's causing the bug?

Any idea what I am doing wrong? Thanks!

My data.table looks like:

```
   ind deg       crp       cdqp        dcp       ddfp       ccp
1:  36   3 0.0000000 0.00000000 0.08694944 0.08819521 1.0000000
2:  36   2 0.0000000 0.00000000 0.04128377 0.05363146 1.0000000
3:  36   1 0.7761228 0.01107921 0.01909992 0.03213586 0.2127980
4:  35   3 0.0000000 0.00000000 0.08949825 0.08173958 1.0000000
5:  35   2 0.0000000 0.00000000 0.04255635 0.04956826 1.0000000
6:  35   1 0.7483854 0.01045624 0.01970272 0.02965017 0.2411584
        ddqp  rv  cv dqv
1: 0.8248554  NA  NA   0
2: 0.9050848  NA  NA   0
3: 0.9487642 100 100   0
4: 0.8287622   0   0  NA
5: 0.9078754   0   0  NA
6: 0.9506471  NA  NA  NA
```

Comment: The most recent thing you did wrong seems to be asking a question without providing reproducible example

Comment: i put everything i am working with up. anything else you need? need help urgently please lemme know

Comment: what is the object `dr` ?

Comment: @BillGong *reproducible example*

Answer (score 0):

I have always bad experiences with `ifelse()`, try,

```
pt[4:108,][ deg != 1 & deg == 3, dqv:=(dr + dr^2 + 1)*mp*shift(dcp, 4-deg)
      +(shift(cv, 4-deg)*shift(dcp, 4-deg)+shift(dqv, 4-deg)*shift(ddqp,
      4-deg))*fm][deg == 1 & deg == 3, dqv:=(dr^2 + 1)*mp*shift(dcp, 4-deg)
      +(shift(cv, 4-deg)*shift(dcp, 4-deg)+shift(dqv, 4-deg)*shift(ddqp,
      4-deg))*fm][deg != 1 & deg != 3, dqv:=(dr + 1)*mp*shift(dcp, 4-deg)
      +(shift(cv, 4-deg)*shift(dcp, 4-deg)+shift(dqv, 4-deg)*shift(ddqp,
      4-deg))*fm][deg == 1 & deg != 3, dqv:=1*mp*shift(dcp, 4-deg)
      +(shift(cv, 4-deg)*shift(dcp, 4-deg)+shift(dqv, 4-deg)*shift(ddqp,
      4-deg))*fm]
```